# Populate an array in flash with data from php

Tags: php, arrays, flash, actionscript

Hi so I need to populate an array in flash with information from php. My php code is :

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
    if (!$db) {
        die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
    }


$db_select = mysql_select_db("profileofperson",$db);
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
    }

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>mySQLtestfile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
<?php
//Step4
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalogue", $db);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row[" Name"]." ".$row["age"]." ".$row["Allergies"]." ".$row["height"]." ".$row["weight"]."<br />";
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

which at present is displaying information from a database. How do i get flash to populate into an array?

Comment: Generate the data in a format compatible with flash. Then make a request in flash to load the data.

Comment: Your PHP code generates HTML, how is this supposed to have anything to do with requesting data from flash? I guess you first need to do some research on Flash and how to retrieve data from a server...

Comment: And, please do not repost [the same (or a very similar) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158449/data-from-php-to-flash-using-actionscipt)...

Comment: Apologies for that but there was an upload error. I've never done this before so I'm asking what is the best way to go about this. Is it best if I use XML as a format?

Answer (score 0):

Make your document xml, not html, start the document like this:

```
<?php

    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo chr(60).chr(63).'xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" '.chr(63).chr(62);
```

This just adds a header tag so the browser/flash recognises the document as XML (similar to !DOCTYPE with HTML) : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Then, query as you are doing, but echo the results in a valid XML format:

```
    echo "<people>";//Create the parent node

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<person>";//Open child node, add values:
            echo "<name>".$row[" Name"]."</name>";
            echo "<age>".$row["age"]."</age>";
            echo "<allergies>".$row["Allergies"]."</allergies>";
            echo "<height>".$row["height"]."</height>";
            echo "<weight>".$row["weight"]."</weight>";
            echo "</person>";//Close child node
    };

    echo "</people>";//Close the parent node

?>
```

I've just written this out off the top of my head so may not be perfect, but it should be easy enough for you to check that it's generating a valid XML document (just load the page in a browser, get an XML viewer plugin to find out more if it's going wrong) and adjust if not, there are millions of tutorials on generating XML pages from PHP.

Then, use the URLLoader class in your flash application to access it:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
//The loader class

var urlRQ:URLRequest = new URLRequest('yoursite/yourpage');
//The URL request    

loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
//Use this for xml

urlRQ.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
//Set method type (normally post)

loader.load(urlRQ);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadedData);
```

Then, have loadedData parse the XML:

```
function loadedData(e:Event):void {

    var people:XML = XML(e.target.data);//Cast this var as XML to access
    //people should represent top-level ie <people>;  

    for each(var person:XML in people.person){//Iterate over member nodes called 'person';
         trace(person.age);//XML object node names can be referenced 
                           //directly with dot notation!
         trace(person.name);//etc...
    }

}
```

One last thing, the mysql_ functions are deprecated in PHP, I found this out recently, use SQLi or PDO instead in future!

Hope this helps, as I say I've written it off the top of my head and it's better that you experiment with it, but if you do get stuck leave a comment and I'll have a look!

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to answer. ok I will get implementing and let you know

Comment: no luck buddy... im receiving a Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';''. when i load the page .But ive written it fine. flash is also experiencing problems with communicating. thing is I need to have each bit of data e.g name, allergies, etc load into separate arrays in flash which then display the ouput in a dynamic textbx

Comment: I haven't tested this code, just wrote it out off the top of my head, I'll set it up when I get time this week and see if I can't spot the error.

Comment: Sure thing. Keep me posted